# How can i create sand surface?

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-10

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi! I want to create a sand surface in gazebo so i will be able to test a wheel and analyse the soil-wheel interactions. To create the sand interface i thought i can create thousands of tiny spheres as particles of the sand and set the physical properties for those particles. I'm pretty new to gazebo, any ideas how can i do this or any other ideas?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24147/how-can-i-create-sand-surface?/) by [Kyriakos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/20484/kyriakos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I don't think you would be able to simulate the collision with every single sand particle. The computation load would be too much. The practical approach could be to set the physics parameters like friction very high so it statistically simulated the sand surface. And if there is other phenomenon that sand exhibits, then write a plugin to include this phenomenon inside the simulation.

When I simulate 1000 balls of 5 cm in radius, the RT factor on my 8 core computer drops to 0.08.

[image: image description]

I spawn the 1000 balls into the simulation by putting following code into the world file (gazebo 7).

```
<population name="ball_population1">
  <model name="ball">
    <static>false</static>
    <link name="ball_body">
      <collision name="ball_collision">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="ball_visual">
        <geometry>
          <sphere>
            <radius>0.05</radius>
          </sphere>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
    </link>
  </model>
  <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
  <box>
    <size>4 4 4</size>
  </box>
  <model_count>1000</model_count>
  <distribution>
    <type>random</type>
  </distribution>
</population>
```

And I had to restart my computer after that.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0